# Accessing JSON decoded into a HASH and an array of hash references

Tags: json, perl, data-structures, hash, perl-data-structures

Given the following dumper output is there a way to iterate through each hash to list only the items under each `results->id` record? I want to be able to say things like:

`print $results{1342}{'domain'};`

and have the statement return `testing11.com` as a result.

Would I have to first read through all of `results` array and then use `$results[$counter]{id}` to access the data in there ?  I'm not sure how to proceed.

```
$VAR1 = { 
          'end_time' => 1466017739,
          'options' => {
                         'hour_offset' => '00',
                         'timezone' => 'America/New_York'
                       },
          'field_headers' => {
                              'priority' => 'Priority',
                              'status' => 'Status',
                              'assignee_external_id' => 'Assignee external id',
                              'initially_assigned_at' => 'Initially assigned at'
                             },
          'results' => [
                         {
                           'priority' => 'High',
                           'status' => 'Open',
                           'domain' => 'testing11.com',
                           'generated_timestamp' => 1546547669,
                           'id' => 1342
                          },
                         {
                           'priority' => 'Low',
                           'status' => 'Open',
                           'domain' => 'testing22.com',
                           'generated_timestamp' => 1464567669,
                           'id' => 7062
                          },
                         {
                           'priority' => 'Low',
                           'status' => 'Closed',
                           'domain' => 'testing33.com',
                           'generated_timestamp' => 1464267669,
                           'id' => 432
                          }]
      }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your dump shows a hashref containing a scalar, two hashrefs, and an arrayref. The arrayref has hashrefs for elements. If you want to retrieve specific elements from it, you need to know the index.

```
$top_level->{results}->[0]->{domain};  # is 'testing11.com'
$top_level->{results}->[0]->{status};  # is 'open'
```

To iterate through it dereference the array

```
foreach my $result (@{ $top_level->{results} }) {
    print "$result->{id}\n";
}
```

Or you can just get values from all `results` elements for a particular key, say for `id`

```
my @ids = map { $_->{id} } @{ $top_level->{results} };
say "@ids";
```

Prints

```
1342 7062 432
```

---

Note that with nested structures, which contain references, you can also use syntax

```
$top_level->{results}[0]{domain};  # is 'testing11.com'
```

The `->` is optional between subscripts, see rule 3. in [Using References in perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Using-References).

When the hash keys are strings they should be quoted

```
$top_level->{'results'}[0]{'domain'};
```

However, a syntax shortcut allows us to omit quotes on barewords. But if there is anything other than a bareword inside `{}` it will be interpreted as an expression *and evaluated*. So if in any doubt use quotes.  You want consistent notation throughout.

Resources: Tutorial [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html), reference [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) and data structures cookbook, [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html).

---

A direct solution is given in [stevieb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1334695/stevieb)'s answer, creating a reverse lookup.  Copied here for reference

```
my $results = $VAR1->{results};

my %by_ip = map {$_->{id} => $_} @$results;

print "$by_ip{1342}->{domain}\n";
```

Comment: @Douglas A little unsure whether you had a more specific need, please let me know if so.

Comment: you've done a great job with many methods. you should throw in my hash example into the mix, as that's specifically what the OP was looking for :)

Comment: @stevieb Thank you for kind words. I'd rather throw in a note to direct them to your answer, which is I now think is exactly what they asked for.  On the other hand, it may be superfluous -- there are the answers, and hopefully they have things covered now.

Comment: my understanding of this site is to provide the best answer possible, and imho, SO is useful for that when I need to search, so don't be shy about taking from my answer, especially when I told you to :P that said, I'm sure it's frowned upon to 'steal' from others answers without at least stating you've done so, but that's clearly not the case here

Comment: you covered many angles, so if you want to add more to your answer from what I posted, I'm down with that. The community will decide which answer is more effective anyhow. For discussions, I belong to perlmonks. For directed information only, I'm here

Comment: either way, I think we've cornered the market on ensuring the OP is covered lol

Comment: @stevieb The OP showed up and did what they wanted, so now I did add your solution to my answer for completeness, as you prompted.  You are right with everything you say of course, but I do like to see scoring as accurate as possible so I was waiting.

Answer (score 2):

You need to transform the inner `$results` array into a new hash:

```
my $results = $VAR1->{results};

my %modded = map {$_->{id} => $_} @$results;

print "$modded{1342}->{domain}\n";
```

Output:

```
testing11.com
```

What that does is for each hash reference inside `@$results`, takes the value of the `id` key, sets it as a new key inside of a new hash (`%modded`), and then assigns the whole hash ref we're working with to the value of that numbered key.

Comment: Ah, right, this may well have been what the OP is about. It crossed my mind that it may need a new data structure but then I decided the other way.

Comment: yeah. I've done this a few ways in the past, this one seemed to work best for this type of struct

Comment: Yes, that's a nice way to turn it around.  What I meant is that I decided to go for more of an overall explanation over a reverse look up.  Good reading of the question :).  Perhaps ... call it `%by_id` or some such?

Comment: Btw, the timing of these comments has been a little funny for me in the past hour or so ... I see them quite a bit later than what the  timestamp shows. Dunno why

Comment: yeah. I've had some ``glitches'' with comments :) it's all my fault. `%by_id` is probably a much better name.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, TIMTOWTDI-ness and `-Ofun` if you use the latest perl (`use v5.24;`), with postfix dereferencing (enabled by default), and experimental support for reference aliasing (`use feature 'refalias';`) then you can dereference `$VAR1` and assign it to an alias (`%data`) which you can then access as a regular hash:

```
use v5.24 ;
use feature 'refaliasing';

my $VAR1 = [AS ABOVE] ;
foreach \my %data ( $VAR1->{results}->@* ) { say $data{domain} };
```

I like this usage (though at this point it is far from an accepted "idiom")  because you invoke the dereferencing syntax "once" - either the postfix or traditional form - and then get a data structure where it is not necessary to use `->` inside the block .

Of course you can do this by copying into a temporary hash. but aliasing can be seen as "more efficient and readable" (*cf.* [`Data::Alias`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Alias)).

---

**Further References**:

- The [Perl Data Structures Cookbook](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html) documentation that comes with perl (`perldoc perldsc` in your shell)
- An accessible [PerlTricks article](https://perltricks.com/article/80/2014/3/27/Perl-references--create--dereference-and-debug-with-confidence/) on references.
- brian d foy's [introduction to `use feature 'refalias'`](http://perltricks.com/article/165/2015/4/10/A-preview-of-Perl-5-22/)   and the [`perldelta`](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.22.0//perldelta.html#Aliasing-via-reference) entry for the feature for version 5.22