# Parse JSON using Perl

Tags: perl, perl-module

I have written a test script to perform certain functions. Script works as expected. Currently,The arguments required to run the script are passed from the command line using `Getopt::Long`.I would like to move the command line  arguments to a json file. The Endpoint ip will  still be passed as command line arg.
I want the endpoint ip to act as a key. For instance, if the endpoint is 1.1.1.1, I want to get the client_ip,client_interface_ip,originip,....,port that is listed under endpoint id 1.1.1.1 in the json config file mentioned below. How do i do that ?

current version of the script:

```
 use Getopt::Long;

     my ($self) = @_;

        GetOptions (
            "endpoint|e=s"           => \$self->{'endpoint'},
            "aggregator|a=s"         => \$self->{'aggregator'},
            "port|pt=s"              => \$self->{'port'},
            "client|c=s"             => \$self->{'client'},
            "client_interface|ci=s"  => \$self->{'client_interface'},
            "origin|o=s"             => \$self->{'origin'},
            "origin_interface|oi=s"  => \$self->{'origin_interface'},
            "interfacename|ot=s"     => \$self->{'i1'},
            "interfacename2|it=s"    => \$self->{'i2'},
             ) || $self->abort( "Invalid command line options.
                   Valid options are endpoint,aggregator,port,client,client_interface,
                     origin,origin_interface,outertunnel,innertunnel,");

       #Terminate the script execution if the reqd args are not passed
       my @required_args = qw(endpoint aggregator port client client_interface            origin origin_interface 
                              );

       for my $command_line_arguments (@required_args) {
         unless ($self->{$command_line_arguments}) {
          $self->abort('missing required argument ' . $command_line_arguments);
         }
       }

  $self->{'tObj'} =  QA::crypto::tunnels->new
      ('host'=> $self->{'endpoint'})
         or $self->abort('[Could not create a QA::Crypto::tunnels object.]');
```

json file  for arguments:

```
{
        "Endpoints": [{

                "endpoint": "1.1.1.1",
                "client_ip": "3.4.5.6",
                "client_interface_ip": "10.11.12.14",
                "origin": "a.a.a.a",
                "origin_interface": "15.16.17.18",
                "interfacename": "name",
                "interfacename2": "name1",
                "sl": 19,
                "port": 362
        }, {

                "endpoint": "2.2.2.2",
                "client_ip": "19.20.21.22",
                "client_interface_ip": "23.24.25.26",
                "origin": "1.2.3.4",
                "origin_interface": "5.6.7.8",
                "interfacename": "interface name",
                "interfacename2": "interfacename_2",
                "sl": 19,
                "port": 366
        }]
}




#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON;

my $json;
{
   open my $fh, "<", "cfg.txt"
      or die("Can't open file \"cfg.json\": $!\n");
   local $/;
   $json = <$fh>;
}

my $data = decode_json($json);
$json = JSON->new->utf8->pretty->encode($data);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first question is about a suitable design for the JSON file. Hashes can serve well here while the arrayref doesn't seem needed at all. The endpoint values can be the keys, with their values being hashrefs with key-related information. Keep the endpoint value in its hashref as well, if you wish.

The key `"Endpoints"` in your JSON doesn't seem to do much as it stands. But if you do need it, perhaps since there will be other types of keys, then you could have for its value another hashref, which will contain the hashref with endpoint values as keys.

For example

```
{ 
   "Endpoints": { 
        "1.1.1.1": { "client_ip": "3.4.5.6",     ... },
        "2.2.2.2": { "client_ip": "19.20.21.22", ... },
        ...
   }, 
   "OtherKeys": { ... }, ...
}
```

The last values should not end with commas. See [JSON format](http://www.json.org/).

When you bring this into Perl you'll have nested hashrefs, like

```
$data = { 
    Endpoints => { 
         1.1.1.1 => { client_ip => '3.4.5.6',     ... }, 
         2.2.2.2 => { client_ip => '19.20.21.22', ... },
    }, 
    OtherKeys => { ... }, 
};
```

Then the values are retrieved simply as

```
my $client_ip = $data->{Endpoints}{'1.1.1.1'}{client_ip};
```

For example, retreive all endpoints and list `client_ip` for them

```
my @endpoints = keys %{$data->{Endpoints}};
foreach my $ip (@endpoints) {
    say $data->{Endpoints}{$ip}{client_ip};
}
```

See [Using References in perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Using-References), and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37845433/accessing-json-decoded-into-a-hash-and-an-array-of-hash-references/37845615#37845615) is entirely about it. Also see [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) and [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html).

We can inspect (*see*) the whole data structure with [Data::Dumper](http://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html)

```
use Data::Dumper;
my $data = decode_json($json);
print Dumper($data);
```

There is a number of other packages for working with nested data structures.

Note that the [JSON](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/JSON-2.90/lib/JSON.pm) package comes with `encode_json` and related methods, so you can create that file programmatically.  This may help in getting its format right and with maintenance in the future.

Comment: If i want to get the client_ip of endpoint 1.1.1.1 , how do i do that ?

Comment: @nims Ah, right. Added to the answer.  I'll add some references for handling hashrefs as well.

Comment: @nims I added some references for handling of hashrefs, the first one for this exact use.  Let me know if the hashref business is a problem -- this is critical to get for using JSON without trouble.

Comment: my $json =  '{
    "Endpoints": {
      "198.18.193.126": {
        "client_ip": "3.4.5.6",
          "client_interface_ip": "9.1.1 .2",
              "origin": "198.18 .193 .151",
                "origin_interface": "8.2 .0 .2",
                        "outertunnel": "tunnel1",
                        "innertunnel": "innertunnel",
                        "slot": 1900,
                        "port": 362
                },
 }';

my $j = JSON->new;
my $data =  $j->decode($json);
my $ client;
 $client = $data->{Endpoints}{198.18.193.126}{client_ip};
print $client;

Comment: im unable to print the value in $client = $data->{Endpoints}{198.18.193.126}{client_ip};  why is that ?

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for the detailed explanation

Comment: quick question. What if the Endpoint  id is part of $self->{'ip'}  ....                   my $client_ip = $data->{Endpoints}{$self->{'ip'}}{client_ip};  i'm sure this won't work. How do i replace the ip with $self->{'ip'} ?

Comment: @nims  I'm not sure what `$self` is, but that should work in fact.  You can have an _expression_ inside `{ ... }`, code -- it should evaluate and its result will be used to look it up in the hash.  So if that `$self->{ip}` returns something that _exists as a key_ for `{Endpoints}` it will work like a charm.

Comment: @nims Let's say `$self->{ip}` returns `198.18.193.126`.  Then this will be looked up, `$data->{Endpoints}{'198.18.193.126'}{client_ip}`.  Since it comes out of an evaluation it is a string so there will no problems with quoting etc.  If there is no such key it will complain. Another option of course is that you do it in two steps, `$ip = $self->{ip}` and then use `$ip` in the hash.

Comment: my @json=    " json file is stored in this array "

  print @json; //prints the json file as expected. 


     my $data =   decode_json(@json);

my $client;

$client = $data->{Endpoints}{'198.18.193.126'}{client_ip};
print $client;               I get the following error :  malformed JSON string, neither array, object, number, string or atom, at character offset 0 (before "(end of string)") at

Comment: @nims  It's telling you that something is in fact nor right with JSON, and at the very beginning -- `character offset 0`. It's the message from `JSON::decode_json`. You can't give it an array `@json`, it has to be a string, `decode_json($string_with_valid_json)`.  What you have in the question is good.

Comment: I get the Json from a different function and that function returns the json in an array..so the Json is in array now..how do I decode it?

Comment: @nims  Huh, it can't be -- read the docs for `decode_json`. What does it look like?  Here is a valid example.  `$json = ' { "key": { "next": "level" } };`. This string, in the variable `$json`,  is valid json. Now decode it `$hr = decode_json($json);`. Now print it `say Dumper($hr);`

Comment: You are right. I fixed it. Thanks for answering my questions.

Comment: @nims  You are welcome.  Come back if there's more.  I'll clean up some of these comments now.